# Issue with Dimension Values in Alerting with CloudWatch Datasource

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable, grafana-alerts, grafana-templating

I'm currently using Grafana version 9.4.7 with AWS CloudWatch as my data source. I have a panel where I'm monitoring the **`SumOffsetLag`** metric from the **`AWS/Kafka`** namespace. I have three dimensions in my setup: **`Cluster Name`**, **`Consumer Group`**, and **`Topic`**.

I'm trying to create an alert based on this panel. However, I'm encountering an issue with the dimension values in the alert configuration. Instead of getting individual values for each dimension, I'm getting all the dimension values concatenated together.

For example, instead of getting:

```
Cluster Name = Cluster Name
Consumer Group = Consumer Group
Topic = Topic
```

I'm getting:

```
Cluster Name = Cluster Name + ConsumerGroup + Topic
Consumer Group = Cluster Name + Consumer Group + Topic
Topic = Cluster Name + Consumer Group + Topic
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbCSW.png)

This is causing issues with my alert configuration, as I'm not able to correctly reference the individual dimension values in the alert message.

I've tried various configurations and syntaxes, but I haven't been able to resolve this issue. I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to correctly reference the individual dimension values in the alert configuration.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Problem is usage of multiple wild char dimension values. Try to use max one '*'.

Comment: @JanGaraj
Thank you for your suggestion. However, the use of wildcard '*' is crucial in my setup. I have multiple consumer groups, and I want the alert to be applicable to all of them. If I don't use the wildcard, the alert would be limited to a specific consumer group, which is not what I want.

Comment: Yes, I understand but that is pointer what can be a problem. So test it, prove that multiple usage of '*' is a problem and then you may open bug report.